# Iteration of NSMutableArray of UITextView causes app to crash

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to iterate Uitextview NsmutableArray but the program crashes and it gives the following error,

```
"""-[__NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x861c2f0"""
```

Please check this code , and give some possible solution...

Thank You...

```
for ( x = 0; x < TextViewArray.count; x++) 
{
    // here TextViewArray is a NSMutableArray  
    UITextView *textField1 = [TextViewArray objectAtIndex:x];
    float diff3;
    diff3 = [textField1.text floatValue];   // The program crashes in this line ,"""""" -[__NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x861c2f0""""" , here I am checking for a float value but i want to use string value instead of float value in this line how to do this?

    NSLog(@"diff3 is %f",diff3);
    textField1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",diff3];
    TXT_First_Tag = [TextViewArray objectAtIndex:x];  // here uitextview *TXT_First_Tag;
    NSLog(@"txt3 is %d",x);           

    TXT_First_Tag.tag = x;       
    NSLog(@" p  is %d", x);  

    //textField1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",diff2];  

    //NSLog(@"Diff is %f",diff2); 
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between `UITextField` and `UITextView`.

Comment: can u show me how u created and entered testview into ur array?

Comment: With your confusion between UITextView & UITextField, I think you should check what you're providing to textField1.text - are you sure that it has a text property for instance? Both UITextField & UITextView do, but you might be passing something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array contains a String at the given index, hence the error """-[__NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x861c2f0""". Check that the Array only contains UITextViews

Answer (score 0):

put a breakpoint before the crash and do a "po" in the gdb shell once control reaches breakpoint. This way you will no if you are trying to access right object or not